# how to fetch specific country from this data set ,which has no root node

Tags: python, dataset

[i entered the covid19 api which displaying all the countries Covid details but how can i get specific country details by user input.this dataset does not show any root node ,i am unable to access the specific country detail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JenZQ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to always check the data type you are dealing with when you failed to do something.

> print(type(k))

In your scenario, you are dealing with JSON data.

json data type are acceble by the key of the values inside it for example:

```
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
y = json.loads(x)
print(y["age"])
```

As I see your data set is inside a list so you can try:

> k[0]['country']

accessing a list element is possible trough their index numbers which are integers not string '0'